# Is there a way to render and export only the horizontal or vertical mesh lines to SVG using Freestyle?

Tags: mesh, freestyle, svg

I seem to be able to export the full (square) mesh to SVG using Freestyle, but I ideally only want to export the horizontal OR vertical mesh lines.

**Example image of successfully exported square mesh (horizontal AND vertical) plus a diagram explaining my question visually:**

[image: example export and diagram of what I'm trying to achieve]

I'm looking to achieve something like the following two images and export to SVG in order to add to apparel designs:

[image: example images created using an app (these are raster and not vector]

[image]

Is this possible and is it achievable using Freestyle? I'm a complete noob to Blender by the way.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exporting process, but one way that could work for this particular mesh is you can CTRL+ALT+LMB a single edge (it should select perpendicular edges in its row) and then ALT+LMB anywhere nearby will make it select the full length of the  edge loop, effectively selecting all edges in one of the directions. Then you could separate them and export.

Comment: Thanks Alex. You're a life saver! I played around with what you suggested (it took me a little while) and by ALT+LMB clicking on a single edge (in edit mode) I could then choose 'Select' > 'Select Loops' > 'Edge Loops' and every corresponding edge in the same direction would then be selected. winner! :)